# how to display 'loading' before content from jquery tabs is loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI tabs and content loaded into the tab is on another page. so it is loading via ajax.  There is some lag between the page loading during which the part of the screen where tab content will load is completley empty.  Is there a way I can show some message like 'loading....' until the content loads?

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

            <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/failedPrescreenReport.jsp</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/failedverificationreport.jsp</a></li>
                    <li><a href="VerificationReport.action</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I have tried using the [spinner](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#option-spinner) option of this plugin but that does not seem to work for me...(maybe my css is messed up)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend listening to the jquery ajaxStart, ajaxStop, and ajaxError events, showing your "loading" popup on ajaxStart, hiding it on AjaxStop and ajaxError.  This way, your loading popup will display whenever an ajax request is pending without any additional programming.

For example:

```
$(function() {
  $(this).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#ajaxLoading").show(); });
  $(this).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#ajaxLoading").hide(); });
 });
```

Comment: +1 - this is pretty standard practice, i believe. if you name your function something and then pass along the name of the "loading" element, you can reuse this function on multiple pages

Comment: #Karmic..Perfect way of doing this. +1

Answer (score 10):

There's no need to do extra stuff, just add **span** tag insdie your anchors. i think it's missed in jQuery's documentation.

example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/failedPrescreenReport.jsp"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/failedverificationreport.jsp"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="VerificationReport.action"><span>Tab 3</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**span** tags are the important part.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this works but it displays “Loading…” or the [`spinner`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-spinner) value in the tab itself not in the tab’s content area.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote [jquery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/) recently that might be helpful. It puts a mask with a spinner over an element, so for your ajax calls you can display the mask before your calls and unmask it in a callback function for example.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery [blockui](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) is perfect for this.  A very quick, elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

blockUI is great, but i'd wager http://plugins.jquery.com/project/loading is a better fit for the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Best Thing I did was just this for ajax driven tabs...Hope you will love this answer

*$("#facilityTabContainer").tabs({ **panelTemplate:"Loading..."**,
                        selected : 0,
                        scrollable : true,
                        cache : false });*

and you can even modify the panelTemplate in jquery.ui.tabs also so that all the tabs in you application will automatically get the 'loading text or image'.
and guess what it also solves your first tab loading problem too..