# JQuery Tabs: How to display a 'Loading...' message' on waiting an AJAX HTTP request response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, message

I am using jQuery UI 1.8.12 and I am implementing [Content via AJAX](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) tabs. I would like to show a "Loading..." message in the meantime the content is loaded (then, of course, the content retrieved with the AJAX HTTP request is displayed).

**How can I do that?**

---

Maybe I can use the [tabTemplate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-tabTemplate) option but I don't know how to accomplish how I can do that.

---

P.S.: I would like to do not use the solution used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082323/display-loading-image-when-ajax-call-is-in-progress) but I would like to add dynamically (in the DOM) the "Loading..." message via jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display 'loading' image when AJAX call is in progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082323/display-loading-image-when-ajax-call-is-in-progress) or [Display loading image while post with ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509711/display-loading-image-while-post-with-ajax) or [jquery ajax tabs change to “Loading…” after clicking on them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644277/jquery-ajax-tabs-change-to-loading-after-clicking-on-them)

Comment: One simple trick that I use is to set the HTML of the element that is loading content to some generic "loading" markup (typically just an animated spinner image) immediately before the AJAX call.  Then when the response comes back the spinner is automatically overwritten with the new data.

Comment: Maybe this? [Add Loading Graphic To JQuery UI Ajax Tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944482/add-loading-graphic-to-jquery-ui-ajax-tabs) Or possibly this? [how to display 'loading' before content from jquery tabs is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019043/how-to-display-loading-before-content-from-jquery-tabs-is-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/). Then it's just a case of adding this to your script:

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

Every time an AJAX request starts, the UI will be blocked by the loading message, and when it stops, the block will fade out and the UI will be usable again.

Comment: I do not want to use an "external" plugin. Just jQuery UI.

Comment: @Backo Out of interest, why is that? jQuery UI itself is an external plugin :) If it's filesize, blockUI is 9kb approx, compared to jQuery UI being at minimum, around 15kb, and more likely to be about 40kb. Unless there's a good reason not to use it, there seems little point re-inventing the wheel :)

Comment: In my previous comment I wrote "Just jQuery" UI because I would like to do not use other plugin more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#example').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.panel).text() == '')
            $(ui.panel).html('Loading...');
        return true;
    },
});
```

Comment: ui.panel.html('Loading...'); ?

Comment: By using your code I get a `ui.panel.html('Loading...') is not a function` error.

Comment: I\You solved my problem: I should use `$(ui.panel).html('Loading...')`.

Comment: *However*, if I do not cache the AJAX HTTP request it will always display the "Loading..." message. So, I would like to dispay that only on the first time it loads the tab content.

Comment: The `if ($(ui.panel).html() == '') ...` statement seems do not work as expected. That is, I see always a blank "body" in the meantime the AJAX HTTP request is performed. Probably a solution is to change the `== ''` with some other similar check, but what?

Comment: Try `if ($(ui.panel).text() == '')` instead of `if ($(ui.panel).html() == '')`. In my code it works.